# Single-ended common mode gain

Tags: common-mode

In the following circuit, what would be the single-ended \$A_{cm}\$? I realise that there would be no current through \$R_e\$ in common mode and that this is a CE (Common Emitter). However, I am not sure whether the single-ended \$A_{cm}\$ should be

\$-\alpha\cdot R_{c1}/(r_{e5}+r_{o3})\$

or rather

\$-\alpha\cdot R_{c1}/(r_{e5}+2r_{o3})\$

I'd appreciate some help figuring it out.
[image]

Comment: The best and proper way to determine the answer is to draw the **small signal model** and analyse that.

Comment: Well, I did that but I am not sure my small signal model is correct. But based on my model I am quite sure the denominator should include \$r_{o3}\$, and not twice that. Yet again, I am not sure.

Comment: Is it essential to attach my drawing in order to get further assistance?

Comment: Since you know no current flows through Re would it matter if you replaced it with an open circuit for your common mode analysis?